# Does any $SU(2)$ matrix have a real eigen basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I'm working on this problem:

Show that a matrix in $SU(2)$ always can be expressed in the form:

$$ A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\exp(i\psi)\cos(\theta) & \exp(i\psi)\sin(\theta) \\ 
-\exp(-i\psi)\sin(\theta) & \exp(-i\psi)\cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\psi,\theta \in \Bbb R$, and $SU(2)$ is a set of $2 \times 2$ [unitary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix) $A$ such that $\det(A) = 1$ .

Noticing that 
$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\exp(i\psi) & \\ 
 & \exp(-i\psi)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ 
-\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

After reading some useful conclusion (about [eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3110124/show-every-x-in-su2-is-conjugate-to-a-matrix-beginbmatrix-ei-theta) and [general form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3111773/general-form-of-elements-of-su2)), I tried solving it by diagonalization, but got stuck on why **there necessarily exist a real eigen basis for any matrix in $SU(2)$**?

Moreover, **is there a better way to prove the statement mentioned above?**

Comment: What is your definition of $SU(2)$?

Comment: Question updated, thanks for suggetion! @Matt

Comment: Does $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$ have a "real eigenbasis"?

Comment: Your example is right, I didn't come up with it. It seems that I went into a dead-end, thank you for reminding!  Now I have no ideas on how to prove the statement. :x @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Isn't
$$\frac15\pmatrix{3i&4\\4&-3i}\in SU(2)?$$

Comment: Did you mean $$\frac{1}{5}\begin{bmatrix}
3i & 4\\ 
-4 & -3i 
\end{bmatrix}$$? I bet there may be something wrong with the problem . Sorry for that. @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: @Rito I meant exactly what I said....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Indeed, $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is diffeomorphic to the sphere $S^3\subset\mathbb{C}^2=\mathbb{R}^4$ which is three-dimensional and hence there is no smooth surjection $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathrm{SU}(2)$ by [Sard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem).

In other words, Sard's theorem tells us that the set of elements of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\psi}\cos\theta & e^{i\psi}\sin\theta \\ -e^{-i\psi}\sin\theta & e^{-i\psi}\cos\theta\end{pmatrix},\quad\psi,\theta\in\mathbb{R}$$
has measure zero in $\mathrm{SU}(2)$.

---

On the other hand, by the [Hopf parametrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-sphere#Hopf_coordinates) of the three-sphere, we can write every element $(\alpha,\beta)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ such that $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$ as 
$$\alpha=e^{i\psi_1}\cos\theta,\quad\beta=e^{i\psi_2}\sin\theta$$
for $\psi_1,\psi_2,\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ and hence every element of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ can be written
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha & \beta \\ -\overline{\beta} & \overline{\alpha}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\psi_1}\cos\theta & e^{i\psi_2}\sin\theta \\ -e^{-i\psi_2}\sin\theta & e^{-i\psi_1}\cos\theta \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: That's a neat and convincing proof(or disproof XD). Could you tell more about Sard's theorem? It seems pretty cool and handy, and I haven't heard it before. Is it under the topic of abstract algebra?

Comment: Isn't Sard's theorem overkill?

Comment: @Rito It is under the topic of [differential geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry), more precisely [smooth manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold).